# Xml Deserialize Class with property object

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization

I would like to know how to deserialize from XML to a class that contains an object which may be any of classes ARS or BRS

ARS and BRS are generated from XSD files
As ARS and BRS both contains property C, then it fails when new Serializer

Error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There was an error reflecting type 'TestXml.Response'.'

InvalidOperationException: Types 'B.C' and 'A.C' both use the XML type name, 'C', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I tried to add namespace to ARS.C and BRS.C
but since the response does not contain the namespace, it returns null

Any suggestion would help, thanks.

Parent class "Response"

```
namespace TestXml
{
    [XmlRoot(Namespace="")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ARS", Type = typeof(ARS))]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BRS", Type = typeof(BRS))]
        public object Object;
    }
}
```

Class ARS

```
namespace A
{
    public class ARS
    {
        public int a;
        public C c;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class C
    {
        public string d;
    }
}
```

Class BRS

```
namespace B
{
    public class BRS
    {
        public int b;
        public C c;
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class C
    {
        public int e;
    }
}
```

Deserialize by XmlSerializer

```
string ooo = @"<Response xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""><ARS><a>1</a><c><d>ca</d></c></ARS></Response>";

 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(ooo);
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

 using (var reader = xDoc.CreateReader(System.Xml.Linq.ReaderOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces))
 {
        Response deserializedObject = (Response)ser.Deserialize(reader);
 }
```

Comment: Trick.  If you can't deserialize the put data into the classes and serialize.  Then compare the serialize xml with the one you are trying to deserialize and see differences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

The request is added with namespace to distinguish between two classes
e.g.
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "A", IsNullable = false)]
    public class C
    {
        public string d;
    }

As the web service provider ignore the namespace in the request, it is ok.
However, the response does not contain the namespace "A", so it cannot be deserialized

Comment: Why do you care about the namespace.  Only the tags names are used by serialize/deserialize.  Use ElementName property if the class name and the xml tags do not match.  : [XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
    public class ARS
    {
    }  XmlRoot can be put before any class to change the name.  Not just the Root of the XML.

Comment: Thanks jdweng.

1st, for Element Name, the web service is created by supplier which I could not control. The response is not under my control. If the ElementName is changed, the object ARS could not be serialized.

Comment: 2nd, for Namespace, there is an error occur during create XmlSerialize when namespace in both classese C in ARS and BRS is set to "" i.e. [XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class C
However,if it is set to different namespaces
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "A", IsNullable = false)] for ARS's C
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "B", IsNullable = false)] for BRS's C
The content of C is null, I guess it is because the namespace is not match, In both scenarios I could not get the correct response object ARS with property C in it.

Comment: It is because you have two classes named C.  Since the element names are different (d & e) I would make one class 'C' and put two properties in the class int d, and string e.

Comment: Thanks jdweng.
As the classes are generated from supplier's xsd, and there are many different classes with same name, it is not applicable to rename all of them.

I finally using xml linq to extract the sub part of the response string first and then deserialize one by one so the conflict does not exist anymore, thanks anyone who commented here

Answer (score 0):

I finally using xml linq to extract the sub part of the response string first and then deserialize one by one so the conflict does not exist anymore